# Common `event` (datetime) table for say a manufacturing DB, an anti pattern?

Tags: database-design

There are many different types of events that can happen during a manufacturing process.
E.g.

- Built Step1
- Build Step2
- Test
- Checked into repairs
- Checkout out of repairs
- Packaged
- Dspatched, etc.

I see two ways to model each step:

1. Have separate independant tables. Each table with its own timestamp field.
2. Extract the timestamp field from the tables, and place it in a common `event` tables which has say 2 fields:

   - `timestamp` field
   - A column which links it to which type of event it is (which table has the specific details for that type of event).
   - Could also have a user field to track who did what etc.

Any reasons why not to use way 2 (`event` table)? It seems advantages for running reports on what events happened during a certain time frame. A way of uniting events in the factory. But my research seems to always point towards avoiding any common function tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an EVENT table sounds reasonable, particularly if there is a set of attributes common to all events. I would tend towards a more descriptive table name, perhaps MANUFACTURING_EVENT (or some terminology used by people in that industry). I would then have detail tables for specific manufacturing events with a FK relationship to the parent.